# Why RECORD_AUDIO is returning permission granted everytime in marshmallow?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am working with media recorder in my application.When I am asking for permission for Record audio in marshmallow and above versions it is returning me permission granted everytime. Here is my code.

```
private static final int REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION = 200;
// Requesting permission to RECORD_AUDIO
private boolean permissionToRecordAccepted = false;
private String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Defined SoundLevelView in main.xml file
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_noice_meter);
    //check for permission
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION:

            permissionToRecordAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

            break;
    }
    if (!permissionToRecordAccepted) {

        finish();
    } else {
        //Task to be done when permission is granted
        //init();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code inside onCreate. Here you are not checking whether permission is granted or not.

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);

    }
}
```

Comment: When i click deny button in requestPermissionResult it is returning grantResult[0] as 0 i.e. PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
private Context mContext=YourActivity.this;

private static final int REQUEST = 112;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};
    if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST );
    } else {
        //do here
    }
} else {
     //do here
}
```

get Permissions Result

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //do here
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to record audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

check permissions  for marshmallow

```
private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Answer (score 0):

New Runtime Permission will work like described only when we set the application's targetSdkVersion to 23. If the application's targetSdkVersion is set to less than 23. It will be assumed that application is not tested with new permission system yet and will switch to the same old behavior: user has to accept every single permission at install time and they will be all granted once installed !

Long story short : Please check yopur target sdkversion first and implement the code as shown by @jitesh mohite